# Composite Non Foreign Key in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using MySQL with SQLAlchemy.

I have 3 columns:

```
 class Exp(db.Model):

   __tablename__ = 'exp'

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True)
   key = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True)
   prefix = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True)
```

In this case, whenever I want to create a `Exp` record, I want to specify one value `prefix`.

I am hoping that `id` will be a unique number generated by the databases autoincrement and the `key` will be a `string` with `prefix` and `id` concatenated. How do I express this relationship in SQLAlchemy models?

It would look like:

Provide `key` as `TEST`.
Database then creates a unique id for the table as `2` and `key` gets set as `TEST-2`.